Acrobat VBA not closing (Document is left open and locked)
When I run this Excel VBA code to add a watermark to an existing PDF file (using Acrobat Pro), the output PDF (OutFileName) remains open in Acrobat.
For example when I try to delete it in Windows, an error pops up, "File In Use, The action can't be completed because the file is open in Adobe Acrobat." Manually opening/closing the PDF file in Windows resolves the issue temporarily.
Obviously, this causes issues when I try to modify the file later. Please help me programmatically close the file cleanly.
Thank you!
    'Add PRELIMINARY Watermark
    If Report_Type = "Preliminary" Then
        Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
        Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI

        'Open the file and add a watermark based on text (using AcroJs)
        If AVDoc.Open(OutFileName, "") Then
           AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript "this.addWatermarkFromText({cText: ""PRELIMINARY"", cFont: ""Times-Roman"", nFontSize: 100, aColor: color.black, nRotation: 45, nOpacity: 0.05});"
        End If

        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set AForm = Nothing
    End If



Clue: I added the line "AVdoc.close" and the PDF file was released. But the watermark was not applied.
Thought: The file needs to be saved before closing.
Searched around for the right lines of code...turns out I have to set PDDoc and then save using that.
    'Add PRELIMINARY Watermark
    If Report_Type = "Preliminary" Then
        Set APP = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
        Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
        Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI

        'Open the file and add a watermark based on text (using AcroJs)
        If AVDoc.Open(PDF_Name, "") Then
           AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript "this.addWatermarkFromText({cText: ""PRELIMINARY"", cFont: ""Times-Roman"", nFontSize: 100, aColor: color.black, nRotation: 45, nOpacity: 0.05});"
        End If

        Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
        PDDoc.Save PDSaveFull, PDF_Name

        AVDoc.Close (True)
        PDDoc.Close
        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set PDDoc = Nothing
        Set AForm = Nothing
        Set APP = Nothing

    End If

